# PyKafka Api usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, pykafka

I am a newbie to Kafka and PyKafka.I know that a producer and a consumer are made in PyKafka via the below code.

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient
client = KafkaClient("localhost:9092")

topic = client.topics["topicname"]
producer = topic.get_producer()
consumer = topic.get_simple_consumer()
```

I want to know what is KafkaClient, and how it is helping in creating producer and consumer.

I have read we can create cluster and broker also using `client.cluster` and `client.broker`, but I can't understand the use of `client` here.

Answer (score 0):

To make terms simpler, replace Kafka with "server".

You interact with servers with  **clients**.

To interact with Kafka, in particular, you send messages to *topics* via *producers*, and get messages with *consumers*.

---

I don't know this library off-hand, but `.broker` and `.cluster` aren't actually "making a Kafka broker / cluster", only establishing a connection to an existing one, from which you can issue later commands.

You need the `client.` on those function calls because the [client is a wrapper around both](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/blob/master/pykafka/client.py#L133-L143)

To know why it is structured in this way, you'd have to ask the developers themselves

Answer (score 0):

`pykafka.KafkaClient` is the root object of the PyKafka API, providing an interface to Kafka brokers as well as the ability to instantiate consumer and producer instances. The `KafkaClient` can be thought of as a representation of the totality of one Python process' interaction with a given Kafka cluster. There is no direct comparison between `KafkaClient` and any of the concepts mentioned in the official Kafka documentation.

It's totally possible in theory to design a python Kafka client library that doesn't have a "client" class like `KafkaClient`. We decided not to since in our opinion a single root class provides a cleaner, more learnable interface than a bag of various classes.